# What is the purpose of pom.properties in STS?

Tags: spring, git, maven

[image]

Hi, I'm making a Spring project now with STS and Git.
However, whenever I try to do Git Push, 
I discover that pom.properties file that I've never worked on is always automatically modified.

1.
So I always ignore it by Git Stash clear or Git Reset.
Is it a smart action?

2.
By the way, what is the purpose of pom.properties file?
I've tried to find the answer on the net, but I couldn't.
Spring help guide also doesn't give me the answer.

I'd be happy if I can get your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in "[Version Informations Into Your Apps With Maven](http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2014/01/02/version-information-into-your-appas-with-maven/)", this file would be used to show a version information in a kind of About Dialog or may be on command line as well.

That file is created by an [archive step](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/#class_archive).

If you wanted to ignore it, you could do:

```
git rm --cached pom.properties
echo pom.properties>>.gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Ignore pom.properties"
git push
```

That way, the file would still be generated/modified, but would no longer be tracked by your Git repository.

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47861478/what-is-the-purpose-of-pom-properties-in-sts/47862820?noredirect=1#comment82693392_47862820) by [Ralph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/280244/ralph), the all target folder should not be in Git (since it can be rebuilt every time)

```
git rm -r --cached target
echo target/>>.gitginore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "Ignore target folder"
git push
```

Comment: You should instruct git to ignore the complete `target` folder!

Comment: @Ralph I agree (I didn't even notice that file was in the maven generated target folder!). I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @VonC Thank you for your kind answer that is very very helpful!

Comment: @Ralph Thank you for your additional information :)